# Django - How can i limit the number of objects that a user can create?

Tags: django, django-models

(first of all sorry for my bad English)

I need to know if i can limit the number of objects that a user can create in a specific model, taking the number of object admitted to create from the user profile.

I go to try to explain this. i have this model

```
class StoreBranchOffice(models.Model):
store = models.ForeignKey(
        StoreBranchOffice,
        verbose_name=_('store branch')
    )
name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        verbose_name=_('name'),
    )
email = models.EmailField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('email'),
    )
phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        verbose_name=_('phone'),
        )
address = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name=_('address'),
    )
```

User Profile Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(
            User,
            verbose_name=_('User'),
        )
    store_branch = models.ForeignKey(
            Store,
            verbose_name=_('Store'),
        )
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    level = models.IntegerField(
            choices=LEVEL_CHOICES,
            default=1,
            verbose_name=_('Level'),
        )
    stores_enable = models.BooleanField(
            default=True,
            verbose_name=_('Stores Enable'),
        )
    branch_max = models.IntegerField(
                default=1,
                verbose_name=_('branches admited')
        )
```

Well, in the userprofile, i have a field that have the number of branch office admitted for the user... 
Well i need to check if the user try to create a branch office, if have admitted create branch office or if the user already have the maximum of branch offices admitted!

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: You want to limit the number of branch offices a user can create? is n't that right??

Comment: You don't have anything here which records which user created an office.

Comment: Exactly, I want to limit the number of branches that the user can create, by taking that number from the user profile in which I have a integer field to assign the maximum

Comment: could you show the relevant user profile? and is there any relation between branches and user profiles? could you show the respective models?

Comment: Already add the model UserProfile. The relation is that each user belongs to one branch.

Comment: a user can only create limited no of StoreBranchOffices, that branch offices must be the ones of the store which is associated to the user isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in views like this,

```
def your_view(request):

    if form.is_valid():
        store = request.user.store_branch
        max_count = request.user.branch_max
        if StoreBranchOffice.objects.filter(store=store).count() >= max_count:
            return #Your error message
```

Or you could do this in your form validation,

```
class StoreBranchOfficeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(StoreBranchOfficeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = StoreBranchOffice
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        store_id = self.cleaned_data.get('store')
        store = Store.objects.get(id=store_id)
        if not store == self.user.userprofile.store:
            raise ValidationError("Not Authorised")
        max_count = self.user.branch_max
        if StoreBranchOffice.objects.filter(store=store).count() >= max_count:
            raise ValidationError("Maximum count of offices reached.")
        return super(StoreBranchOfficeForm, self).clean()
```

Then it will be validated when you call `form.is_valid()` in your view everytime..

But you need to pass user into the form each time,

```
    form = StoreBranchOfficeForm(user=request.user)
```